# Prove that the quadrilateral formed by connecting the midpoints of a quadrilateral is a parallelogram.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

Given a quadrilateral $ABCD$, prove that the quadrilateral formed by its midpoints, $EFGH$, is a parallelogram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Since EH is a midline of triangle ABD, $EH \parallel BD$. Likewise, $FG \parallel BD$ looking at triangle BCD. Therefore $EH \parallel BD \parallel FG$. Similarly you can show $EF \parallel HG$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:** Let vectors $a,b,c,d$ go from an (arbitrary but fixed) origin to points $A,B,C,D$. Then

1. Express the vectors from the origin to the midpoints $E,F,G,H$, using $a,b,c,d$.
2. Conclude that $\vec{EF}=\vec{HG}$.

Answer (score 0):

E,F,G,H are midpoint (given)
HE=1/2AC (by middline theorem)
FG=1/2AC(by middline theorem)
HE=FG (by transitive property)
EF=1/2DB(by middline thm)
HG=1/2DB(by middline thm)
EF=HG (by transitive property)
EFGH is a parallelogram (by definition of parallelogram)

Comment: E,F,G,H are midpoint (given)
HE=1/2AC (by middline theorem)
FG=1/2AC(by middline theorem)
HE=FG (by transitive property)
EF=1/2DB(by middline thm)
HG=1/2DB(by middline thm)
EF=HG (by transitive property)
EFGH is a parallelogram (by definition of parallelogram)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) may be helpful for formatting your posts to make them more readable.